# VSCODE: How do i enable "tasks: Allow Automatic Tasks In Folder" by default?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

I want "tasks: Allow Automatic Tasks In Folder" to be enabled by default when i open a project

this is the tasks.json

```
{
"version": "2.0.0",
"tasks": [
    {
        "type": "npm",
        "script": "gulp",
        "runOptions": {
            "runOn": "folderOpen"
        }
    }
]
```

}

it runs on start but only if i call "tasks: Allow Automatic Tasks In Folder" via cmd+shift+p and reopen the project

i need this to be enabled by default. How can i do that ?

Comment: Does the `"runOn": "default"` option do what you want?

Comment: hey Mark thx for the reply :) unfortunately not .. with  "runOn": "default" 
it wont fire on startup at all .. in this scenario i need to call "npm run gulp" manually in the vscode-terminal

Comment: You may have to select the command "Tasks: Allow Automatic Tasks in Folder" in the command palette.  And then I had to do a couple of restarts or reloads to get it to work the first time and then it seems better.  With `"runOn": "folderOpen"`.

Comment: Sorry, I see that you were previously doing the command.  I did have to do a couple of full restarts to get it to work.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56738821/is-it-possible-to-create-a-vs-code-extension-that-runs-a-specific-gulp-task/56745902#56745902

Comment: In VSCode 1.40.0 you have to open the task palette and first select `Tasks: Manage Automatic Tasks in Folder` then you can select `Allow Automatic Tasks in Folder`

Comment: @kumar303  Your comment is an answer.  I'll give you a chance to post it as answer otherwise I will in a couple days.

Comment: @c-perkins mine isn't an answer. What the OP is asking for is impossible. I only commented because there was a change in some version of VSCode that added an extra menu item before you can select what the OP described as the current workaround. Hopefully this helps someone who was confused (like me).

Comment: Actually once you set `Allow Automatic Tasks in Folder`, it works every time you open the folder.

Comment: This is a good question. But might need a rephrase: Where is the setting *Allow Automatic Tasks in Folder* stored and how can I activate it for all projects?

Comment: @theking2 The [setting is now (July 2022) here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72923640/6309) with VSCode 1.70.

Answer (score 3):

With VSCode 1.70 (July 2022) and [issue 64618](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/64618), there will also be a *setting* associated with the command "`Allow Automatic Tasks in Folder`".

See [PR 154171](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/154171) and [commit 755d39f](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/commit/755d39f1e079d103fc7f6dce43e9bc00071f24fe)

There is now a `task.allowAutomaticTasks` to enable automatic tasks in the folder, with:

- `task.allowAutomaticTasks.on`: Always
- `task.allowAutomaticTasks.auto`: Prompt for permission for each folder
- `task.allowAutomaticTasks.off`: Never

This is available today (July 2022) in the [insider release](https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders/).

Answer (score 0):

Until VSCode 1.70 (July 2022) it was not possible to **Allow Automatic Tasks in Folder** by default. It has to be set by the instructions of Manuel Lehenberger.

1. In VScode type **Ctrl+Shift+p**
2. Search and select `Tasks: Manage Automatic Tasks in Folder`
3. Click `Allow Automatic Tasks in Folder`

This has to be done once only. (for every project folder). I make it my routine when creating a new project folder or workspace.

Btw the `tasks` - section can be incorperated in the `.code-workspace` file thus removing the need for a `.vscode` folder and `tasks.json` file and reducing the clutter.

EDIT: Outdated