# Is it possible to create a VS Code extension that runs a specific gulp task?

Tags: visual-studio-code, gulp, visual-studio-extensions

Since I'm a lazy programmer, I've built a gulp task that does some minor tasks for me but I'd like to turn this into an extension so I can install it on my computer and it just "works". Like I install it, boot up VS code and the tasks execute and start watching my code automatically.

I haven't found much things online but then again I could be googling the wrong things. Anything helps - thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [run task on folderOpen option: vscode docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/tasks#_run-behavior).

This works for me:

```
// in tasks.json

{
  "label": "Tasks: copy3",
  "type": "shell",
  "command": "gulp",
  "args": [
    "copy3",
    "--file",
    "${fileBasename}"
  ],
  "problemMatcher": [],
  "runOptions": {
    "runOn": "folderOpen"
  }
},
```

Now the `copy3` task in gulpfile.js will automatically be run when that folder (or workspace) is opened.  You may have to select `Tasks: Allow Automatic Tasks in Folder` first in the command palette.  And definitely reload.

No extension - it is built-in behaviour more recently.  See [run task on folder open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34103549/can-i-automatically-start-a-task-when-a-folder-is-opened).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like *Yuki Doi* had you to it with ["Blade Runner"](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=yukidoi.blade-runner). This extension does exactly what you're looking for, it  automatically runs build task when a folder is opened.

[Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34103549/can-i-automatically-start-a-task-when-a-folder-is-opened)