# Run terminals on vscode start

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want a few terminals opened when I start vscode. The [docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal#_automating-launching-of-terminals) show how to do it.

My `.vscode/tasks.json`:

```json
{
  "label": "create terminals",
  "runOptions": { "runOn": "folderOpen", },   // <--- should run task on vscode start (but doesn't)
  "dependsOn": [ "foo", "bar" ],
},
{ "label": "foo", "type": "shell", "command": "/bin/zsh", "options": { "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/foo/", }, "isBackground": true, "problemMatcher": [], "presentation": { "echo": false, "panel": "dedicated", "focus": false, "reveal": "never", "group": "terminals" } },
{ "label": "bar", "type": "shell", "command": "/bin/zsh", "options": { "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/bar/", }, "isBackground": true, "problemMatcher": [], "presentation": { "echo": false, "panel": "dedicated", "focus": false, "reveal": "never", "group": "terminals" } },
```

That does not run on vscode start. *However it works as expected when I run it manually.*

How do I make it run on vscode start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems there is more to it - one must also [enable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34103549/can-i-automatically-start-a-task-when-a-folder-is-opened#comment105445234_53755091) "automatic tasks".

Like this: <kbd>ctrl + p</kbd>, *"Manage Automatic Tasks in Folder"*, *"Allow Automatic Tasks in Folder"*.

Apparently this will be exposed as a [setting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72923640/9971404) in the next vscode version (1.70)